# Is there a solution to use Mongodb query expression into aggregate match?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am using mongoose package in node.js
I was originally using Model.find to get the list of the objects and now i am changing this into using aggregate. But in this case, original find expressions no more work there.
Any good solution to save time?

Comment: Please elaborate what you tried, mention your original queries and changes you made.

Comment: There shouldn't be much difference between `.find()` & `.aggregate()`, Any reason why you're switching for ?